# how does check works, im having a problem

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using check constraint to check whether the entry is either male or female, but for some reason it is not working. OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

I tried modifying every bit of the code, but nothing worked

```
 ALTER TABLE BANK ADD GENDER VARCHAR(1) 
      CHECK(GENDER = 'M' OR 'F' OR 'T') AFTER NAME;
```

I want only M and F in the entry, nothing else.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? (this is a critical piece of information, so please include it).

Comment: 'Prior to MySQL 8.0.16, CREATE TABLE permits only the following limited version of table CHECK constraint syntax, which is parsed and ignored:' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html 'As of MySQL 8.0.16, CREATE TABLE permits the core features of table and column CHECK constraints, for all storage engines.' , The optional enforcement clause indicates whether the constraint is enforced:''

Comment: You might consider enum as an alternative https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html or creating a gender table and adding a foreign key on gender or creating a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not support `check` in versions prior to 8. It gets parsed but does nothing.

You can use a trigger to check the values and abort the execution in your trigger if the values are not what you expect.

```
delimiter //
  CREATE TRIGGER BANK_check_gender BEFORE INSERT ON BANK 
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
   IF NEW.GENDER not in ('M', 'F', 'T')
   THEN
       SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' 
       SET message_text = 'invalid gender';
   END IF
END
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: My guess is that the OP is using an earlier version, but you might want to add the correct answer if using MySQL 8+ `:-)`